# Android use canvas draw custom shape

Tags: android, canvas

I have L T R B positions. I want to draw a rounded rectangle.
Here is my code:

```
override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas?) {
    super.onDraw(canvas)
    val curvePath = Path().apply {
        moveTo(left.x, left.y)
        lineTo(bottom.x, bottom.y)
        arcTo(bottom.x, right.y, right.x, bottom.y, 135f, 315f, false)
        lineTo(top.x, top.y)
        arcTo(left.x, top.y, top.x, left.y, 315f, 135f, false)
    }
    canvas?.drawPath(curvePath, paint)
}
```

I don't understand arcTo() method, so how can I draw a rounded rectangle like the attached image (2 curved path are semi-circle)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is a addRoundRect method in Path, easier than adding parts separately.

```
addRoundRect(float left, float top, float right, float bottom, float rx, float ry,Direction dir)
```